# xml to mysql with php childnotes

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, xml, dom

I created the following for xml to mysql. How can i put all *optie* in a comma seperate mysql field? Im only getting now 1 value. I like to have an array like (Airbags Zij, Bestuurderstoel..)

The database type  [opties]  is: text - latin1_swedish_ci. The multiple opties should be imported into one row (comma seperated)

Thank for the help

```
<?php
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("sample.xml");
$mysql_hostname = "localhost"; // Example : localhost
$mysql_user = "user";
$mysql_password = "pass";
$mysql_database = "database";

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$mysql_database};host={$mysql_hostname};     port=3306", $mysql_user, $mysql_password);

$xmlObject = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('occasion');
$itemCount = $xmlObject->length;

for ($i=0; $i < $itemCount; $i++){
$hexnr = $xmlObject->item($i)->getAttribute('id');
$verkoopprijs_particulier = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('prijs')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$voertuigsoort = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$kenteken = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('kenteken')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$merk = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('merk')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$model = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('model')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$carrosserie= $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('carrosserie')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$brandstof = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('brandstof')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$kleur = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('kleur')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$transmissie = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('transmissie')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$uitvoering = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('uitvoering')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$bouwjaar = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('bouwjaar')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$tellerstand = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('kilometerstand')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$cilinderinhoud = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('cilinderinhoud')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$napweblabel = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('napweblabel')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$omschrijving= $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('omschrijving')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$verkoper= $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('verkoper')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$postcode= $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('postcode')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$plaats= $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('plaats')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$fotoklein = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('klein')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$fotogroot = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('groot')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$opties = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('optie')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

$sql = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `voertuigen` (`hexnr`,`verkoopprijs_particulier`,`voertuigsoort`,`kenteken`, `merk`, `model`, `carrosserie`,  `brandstof`, `kleur`, `transmissie`, `uitvoering`, `bouwjaar`, `tellerstand` , `cilinderinhoud`, `napweblabel` , `fotoklein`, `fotogroot`, `omschrijving`, `verkoper`, `postcode`, `plaats`, `opties`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)");
$sql->execute(array(
 $hexnr,
 $verkoopprijs_particulier,
 $voertuigsoort,
 $kenteken,
 $merk,
 $model,
 $carrosserie,
 $brandstof,
 $kleur,
 $transmissie,
 $uitvoering,
 $bouwjaar,
 $tellerstand,
 $cilinderinhoud,
 $napweblabel,
 $fotoklein,
 $fotogroot,
 $omschrijving,
 $verkoper,
 $postcode,
 $plaats,
 $opties
            ));
print "Finished Item $omschrijving n<br/>";
}
```

part of my xml:

```
<occasion id="140969">
<cilinderinhoud>1984</cilinderinhoud>
<napweblabel>nee</napweblabel>
<verkoper><![CDATA[Autobedrijf CarSelect en zn.]]></verkoper>
<opties>
    <optie><![CDATA[Airbag Zij]]></optie>
    <optie><![CDATA[Bestuurdersstoel In Hoogte Verstelbaar]]></optie>
    <optie><![CDATA[Boordcomputer]]></optie>
    <optie><![CDATA[Buitenspiegels In Carrosseriekleur]]></optie>
    <optie><![CDATA[Bumpers In Carrosseriekleur]]></optie>
    <optie><![CDATA[Elektrisch Verstelbare Buitenspiegels]]></optie>
    <optie><![CDATA[Elektrische Ramen]]></optie>
    <optie><![CDATA[Lichtmetalen Velgen]]></optie>
    <optie><![CDATA[Metallic Lak]]></optie>
    <optie><![CDATA[Stuurbekrachtiging]]></optie>
    <optie><![CDATA[Toerenteller]]></optie>
    <optie><![CDATA[Verstralers]]></optie>
    <optie><![CDATA[Verwarmde Buitenspiegels]]></optie>
</opties>
</occasion>
```

Thanks

Comment: Which data base type has the field `opties` in the data base?

Comment: There are multiple *opties*. Are they to be imported on different rows?

Comment: The database type  [opties]  is:   text  - latin1_swedish_ci.The multiple opties should be imported into one row (comma seperated)